# jQuery Accordion Trigger outside the element

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a single drop down using the accordion jQuery plugin but I want the trigger to be a link that is way on the other side of the page, outside the element that drops down.

possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correcly, you want to trigger an accordion from an outside link.

You could use :

```
$( "#accordionId" ).accordion( "option", "active", idxToActivate );
```

A fast example :

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>

<a href='#' onclick='$( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", 1 );'>test</a>
```

SCRIPT

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#accordion').accordion({});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

Say your triggers are like:

```
<a href="#" class="accordionLink">1</a>
<a href="#" class="accordionLink">2</a>
<a href="#" class="accordionLink">3</a>
```

Then you provide:

```
$(".accordionLink").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).text();
    // check if it is already active by checking for the existence of a class on the
    //header
    id = +id - 1;
    if(!$("#sec_" + id).hasClass("ui-state-active")) {
        $( "#accordionId" ).accordion('activate', id);
    }
});
```

If your triggers are different than the accordion IDs, then you will have to use a mapping of triggers to accordion IDs.

Comment: I'm not able to get this function the way you have it. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @Michael - what do you mean by "not able to get".  I've changed the activate to be simpler and added a guard for invoking the link on an open accordion.

Comment: I'm still not understanding. it's still not simple enough for me :(

Comment: @Michael - where are you not following?  Do you understand the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler for jQuery?  What about the [activate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#method-activate) method on the accordion?  Is it the use of the ID that isn't making sense?  Something else?

Comment: @Michael - I made a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jcjNW/1/) and realized that the ID needs to be zero-based.  Anything else I can explain?  Check out the demo to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks I'm getting much closer. Unfortunately adding 1.5.1 or jqueryui breaks preexisting jquery calls. I'm using jQuery 1.3

Comment: Also I can't seem to create it using only one element (instead of 3)

Comment: So, wait, which accordion are you using?  That might make a difference in how it works.  Also, what is your one element and how do you determine which ID to activate?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.3

jq13(document).ready(function() {
 
 jq13('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
  jq13('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal'); 
  jq13(this).next().slideDown('normal');
 });
 jq13("div.accordionContent").hide();

});

Comment: @Michael - and [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/accordion) plugin?  Have you seen [the last demo on this page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/) for the last standalone release of the plugin?

Comment: Thanks but that just makes the second accordion control the one above.
I have one drop down that I want to be triggered on a different part of the page

Comment: @Michael - can you update the question with the code you have, or a demo showing what you've tried?

Comment: I solved it using http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm